# copy content of folder to multiple sub folders

Tags: bash, scripts

So i'm trying to understand if its possible to copy the contents of a template folder into multiple existing folders.

So i have

```
opt/application/tenant_template
opt/application/tenant_template/src
opt/application/tenant_template/table
opt/application/tenant_template/attachments.bar
```

All these files should be copied to the folders random_1 random_2 random_3 but i dont know what the names of the random_* folders are.

```
opt/application/tenant/random_1
opt/application/tenant/random_2
opt/application/tenant/random_3
```

Is this possible or even advisable?

Answer (score 1):

Use `find`:

```
find opt/application/tenant -type d -name "random_*" \
  -exec cp -pri opt/application/tenant_template/* {}/ \;
```

Alternatively, use a `for`-loop:

```
for t in opt/application/tenant/random_*; do
    cp -pri opt/application/tenant_template/* "$t"
done
```

---

--> `cp` options:

- `-p` preserve permissions and timestamps
- `-r` recursive
- `-i` interactive (ask before overwrite)

Comment: think you should add -maxdepth on find... just to be safe

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

```
for dir in /opt/application/tenant/random_*/; do 
  cp -r /opt/application/tenant_template/* $dir
done
```

Comment: @damadam I'm sorry, could you point the mistake in my code? (I added full paths now).

Comment: better use cp -a i think